# add 3G detection to the following code

Tags: ios, objective-c, reachability

I have a method that checks for **Wi-Fi** that i got from an old project that i had, now i need to actually make it check for **3G** or **Wifi**, and if none available give the error message.

Original sample working:

```
- (BOOL)checkForWIFIConnection {

    Reachability* wifiReach = [Reachability reachabilityForLocalWiFi];
    NetworkStatus netStatus = [wifiReach currentReachabilityStatus];
    if (netStatus!=ReachableViaWiFi)
    {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Sem conexão à internet!", @"AlertView")
                                                            message:NSLocalizedString(@"Não está conectado à internet. Tente novamente após se connectar.", @"AlertView")
                                                           delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"AlertView")
                                                  otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alertView show];
        return NO;
    }
    else {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

---

How do i make it check for ReachableViaWWAN ? can i just add it here (<-) ??

```
- (BOOL)checkForWIFIConnection {

        Reachability* wifiReach = [Reachability reachabilityForLocalWiFi];
        NetworkStatus netStatus = [wifiReach currentReachabilityStatus];
        if (netStatus!=ReachableViaWiFi && ReachableViaWWAN) <- (i get an error saying use of logical && with constant operand)
        {
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Sem conexão à internet!", @"AlertView")
                                                                message:NSLocalizedString(@"Não está conectado à internet. Tente novamente após se connectar.", @"AlertView")
                                                               delegate:self
                                                      cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"AlertView")
                                                      otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [alertView show];
            return NO;
        }
        else {
            return YES;
        }
    }
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change:

```
Reachability* wifiReach = [Reachability reachabilityForLocalWiFi];
```

to:

```
Reachability* wifiReach = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
```

and

```
if (netStatus!=ReachableViaWiFi)
```

to:

```
if (netStatus == NotReachable)
```

In other words:

```
Reachability* wifiReach = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
NetworkStatus netStatus = [wifiReach currentReachabilityStatus];
if (netStatus == NotReachable)
{
```

BTW - please consult an Objective-C tutorial to learn how to write compound expressions. Your `if` statement would need to be something like:

```
if (netStatus!=ReachableViaWiFi && netStatus!=ReachableViaWWAN)
```

but while this will solve the compiler issue, it won't work for your code because the `WWAN` value won't ever be given when using `reachabilityForLocalWiFi`.